# Which database should I use for a rule-based language?

Tags: database, jess

I wrote rules in Jess, which database should I use to store them?

Comment: Why do you want to store rules in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jess has no built-in capability for storing rules in a database; it works with flat files, either text or XML. To use a database, you'd have to implement code yourself to retrieve (and store) them. As such, there's not much we can do to help you choose a database, as Jess won't care.

Comment: thanks,which database should I use to text data?

Comment: Why do you think you need a database? As I said, you don't.